# Sharing the Local IIS application using Web Server

Tags: networking, webserver, iis, localhost, windows-server-2012

We have an Asp.net Web application with Oracle DB as backend, configured in windows server 2012 IIS (8.0). I want to share the local server application URL using another web server which is connected through LAN, so that we can access the URL anywhere from internet.

Answer (score 1):

If the "another web server" is IIS as well: [Setting up a Reverse Proxy using IIS, URL Rewrite and ARR](http://blogs.iis.net/carlosag/archive/2010/04/01/setting-up-a-reverse-proxy-using-iis-url-rewrite-and-arr.aspx)